# Strange Output When Write Using NFC

Tags: android, eclipse, tags, nfc, writer

so now i have a project of NFC, i write a vcard file but the output is not what i want this is the code:

```
 private NdefMessage getNoteAsNdef() {
 //   byte[] textBytes = mName.getText().toString().getBytes();
//    EditText tName = mName;
//    EditText tNumber = mNumber;





    String nameVcard = "BEGIN:VCARD" +"\n"+ "VERSION:2.1" +"\n" + "N:;" + (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mName) + "\n" +"ORG:"+"\n"+ "TEL;WORK:" +(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mNumber)+ "\n" + "END:VCARD";
    byte[] uriField = nameVcard.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    byte[] textBytes = new byte[uriField.length + 1];;
    System.arraycopy(uriField, 0, textBytes, 1, uriField.length);

    NdefRecord textRecord = new NdefRecord(
            NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, "text/x-vcard".getBytes(), new byte[0], textBytes);

    return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        textRecord
    });
}
```

the output is some kind of weird word and always have an "@"

i don't get it, is there something i must add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String nameVcard = "BEGIN:VCARD" +"\n"+ "VERSION:2.1" +"\n" + "N:;" + (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mName) + "\n" +"ORG:"+"\n"+ "TEL;WORK:" +(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mNumber)+ "\n" + "END:VCARD";
```

you are using directly toString() on the EditText object. You should change

```
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mName)
```

with

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mName)).getText().toString()
```

for every `EditText`

Comment: thanks for your answer @blackbelt it works! so can i ask again? i have the same problem when write URL but i'm sure that i used this method

this is the code

    private NdefMessage getNoteAsNdef() {
        byte[] textBytes = mLink.getText().toString().getBytes();
        NdefRecord textRecord = NdefRecord.createUri("http://"+ textBytes);
        return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
            textRecord
        });

Comment: I see. Here lies your error: NdefRecord textRecord = NdefRecord.createUri("http://"+ textBytes); your are calling toString() on the byte[] array. You should replace NdefRecord.createUri("http://"+ textBytes); with NdefRecord.createUri("http://"+ mLink.getText().toString());

Comment: and it worked again! thanks a lot @blackbelt ! if you don't mind, i wanna ask one more thing, but i guess it's easier to see as a new question, so here's the link [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427421/write-text-on-nfc-tag-but-my-reader-cant-read-it

Answer (score 1):

If you use `(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mName)` and plus `+` a String, it will get the method `toString` of editText .This is not what you want to get.So you should use `((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mName)).getText().toString()` instead.